# Pass a file name as a command line argument to GNU Octave script

Tags: file, matlab, octave

In an executable Octave script, I want to pass the name of a file containing a matrix and make gnu octave load that file information as a matrix. How do I do that?

Here is what the script should look like

```
#! /usr/bin/octave -qf

arg_list = argv()

filename = argv{1} % Name of the file containing the matrix you want to load

load -ascii filename % Load the information
```

The file passed will be a matrix containing a matrix of arbitrary size say 2x3

```
1 2 3
5 7 8
```

At the command line the script should be run as `./myscript mymatrixfile`
where `mymatrixfile` contains the matrix.

This is what I get when I try to execute the script just written above with octave

```
[Desktop/SCVT]$ ./octavetinker.m generators.xyz                                                                             (05-14 10:41)
arg_list =

{
  [1,1] = generators.xyz
}

filename = generators.xyz
error: load: unable to find file filename
error: called from:
error:   ./octavetinker.m at line 7, column 1

[Desktop/SCVT]$
```

Where `generators.xyz` is the file containing the matrix I need

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/octave -qf

arg_list = argv ();
filename = arg_list{1};
load("-ascii",filename);
```

when you wrote the line `load filename` you indicated to the load function to load the file name "filename".  That is to say, you did the thing that is equivalent to `load('filename');`.

In both MATLAB and Octave, a function "foo" followed by a space then the word "bar" indicates that bar is to be submitted as a string to foo. This is true even if bar is a defined variable in your workspace.